# Dealing with back transforming log in R

Tags: r, logging, skew

I am currently a bit lost with back transforming log with random forests.
I started to use log for the dependent variable because it is skewed.

I made a simple bagging random forest and a "tuned" forest which works better on test data than the bagging model (RMSE of `0.2058421` for the bagging model and RMSE of `0.2004765` for the random forest), but when I transform
them back to normal using

```
sqrt(mean((exp(cars_test$Price) - exp(bag_prediction))^2))
sqrt(mean((exp(cars_test$Price) - exp(rf_prediction))^2))
```

I get an RMSE of `5050.66` with the bagging model vs an RMSE of `5178.076` with the random forest.
This is where I am lost... Why is the bagging model better all of a sudden? Is there something I should change in the way I am back transforming the log price or is this just how it works?

I have looked at a few other stackoverflow questions about back transforming log, where some recommended using the way I described above. However non of them mentioned anything about the better model coming out worse after transforming back?

Comment: It's very possible that, using RMSE as a metric, one model is better on the log scale and the other is better on the untransformed scale, like you have here. Overall I would say this is more of a statistical question than a programming question - so it may be a better question for stats.stackexchange than Stack Overflow - though I'm not really sure what the question is.